# How to combine two columns as one primary key sql

Tags: sql, h2db

I have a database contain a table of id cards like this query

```
CREATE TABLE ID_CARD 
(
    N_CARD          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ISSUE_DATE      DATE NOT NULL,
    ID_TYPE         VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PKEY_ID_CARD PRIMARY KEY(N_CARD, ISSUE_DATE)
);
```

but an id card can have the same `N_CARD` but with different `ISSUE_DATE` and also an id card can have the same `ISSUE_DATE` but diffrent `N_CARD` so two id cards can't have the same `N_CARD` and `ISSUE_DATE` at the same time.

With SQL Workbench/j the SQL source for this table is

```
    DROP TABLE ID_CARD;

CREATE CACHED TABLE ID_CARD
(
   N_CARD      VARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL,
   ISSUE_DATE  DATE          NOT NULL,
   ID_TYPE     VARCHAR(2)    NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ID_CARD
   ADD CONSTRAINT PKEY_ID_CARD
   PRIMARY KEY (N_CARD, ISSUE_DATE);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FKEY_N_CARD_CLIENT_INDEX_8
   ON ID_CARD (N_CARD ASC);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FKEY_ISSUE_DATE_CLIENT_INDEX_8
   ON ID_CARD (ISSUE_DATE ASC);
```

When I execute this query

```
INSERT INTO ID_CARD (N_CARD, ISSUE_DATE, ID_TYPE)
VALUES ('101215', DATE '2019-11-11', 'DL');
commit;
INSERT INTO ID_CARD(N_CARD,ISSUE_DATE,ID_TYPE)VALUES('101215',DATE '2019-11-12','DL');
commit;
```

this error

```
Unique index or primary key violation: "FKEY_N_CARD_CLIENT_INDEX_8 ON 

PUBLIC.ID_CARD(N_CARD) VALUES ('101215', 9)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO ID_CARD(N_CARD,ISSUE_DATE,ID_TYPE)VALUES('101215',DATE '2019-11-11','DL') [23505-193] [SQL State=23505, DB Errorcode=23505]
```

the question is how  to represent thid situation in the database ?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?  That seems to be the right way to do what you want.

Comment: the error whe i insert two id cards with the same N_CARD and diffrent ISSUE_DATE

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Unique index or primary key violation: "FKEY_N_CARD_CLIENT_INDEX_8 ON PUBLIC.ID_CARD(N_CARD) VALUES ('101215', 9)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO ID_CARD(N_CARD,ISSUE_DATE,ID_TYPE)VALUES('101215',DATE '2019-11-11','DL') [23505-193] [SQL State=23505, DB Errorcode=23505]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two unique indexes as

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FKEY_N_CARD_CLIENT_INDEX_8
    ON ID_CARD (N_CARD ASC);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FKEY_ISSUE_DATE_CLIENT_INDEX_8
    ON ID_CARD (ISSUE_DATE ASC);
```

you need a single unique index as

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FKEY_N_DT_CLIENT_INDEX_8
    ON ID_CARD (N_CARD ASC, ISSUE_DATE ASC);
```

Comment: what the use of ASC  in this case

Comment: the same problem the unique index of N_CARD and of ISSUE_DATE remain @Mark Adelsberger

Comment: @A.Ilyes - I don't presume to know why the index columns were defined as they were; I'm addressing the problem without unnecessary changes to the code

Comment: @A.Ilyes - If the problem remains, I would conclude that you did not remove the individual unique indexes.

Comment: the individual unique index it created by default with db managment system but when i add a new column contain integer auto_increment and add N_CARD and ISSUE_DATE ass a unique key the problem solved thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your first `create table` statement is correct for what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE ID_CARD (
    N_CARD          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    ISSUE_DATE      DATE NOT NULL,
    ID_TYPE         VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PKEY_ID_CARD PRIMARY KEY(N_CARD, ISSUE_DATE)
);
```

However, the unique indexes are *incorrect*:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FKEY_N_CARD_CLIENT_INDEX_8 ON ID_CARD (N_CARD ASC);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FKEY_ISSUE_DATE_CLIENT_INDEX_8 ON ID_CARD (ISSUE_DATE ASC);
```

I don't know why these are being created, but you should drop them.

Answer (score 0):

hi i solve my problem with this query

```
CREATE TABLE ID_CARD(
ID              INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
N_CARD          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
ISSUE_DATE      DATE NOT NULL,
ID_TYPE         VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PKEY_ID_CARD PRIMARY KEY(ID),
CONSTRAINT UI_ID_CARD UNIQUE INDEX(N_CARD,ISSUE_DATE)
);
```

i don't know if this is a good solution but my problem is solved 
any optimization i'm here